# R - Create new variables from dataframe using with()

Tags: r

I learned one should avoid using attach. And to use with() instead.
However, sometimes it seems that is not a solution in all cases.

I need to create several new variable (matrices), caclulated from one and the same value in a data.frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Var1=rnorm(50,5), Var2=rnorm(50,12))

q5 <- quantile(df1$Var1,.05, na.rm=TRUE)# lower quantile
q95 <- quantile(df1$Var1,.95, na.rm=TRUE) # upper quantile
medx <- median(df1$Var1, na.rm=TRUE) # median
x.dens <- density(df1$Var1, na.rm=TRUE) # density
```

I want to avoid the burdensome/redundant use of "data.frame$"

but this does not work:

```
with(df1, 
q5 <- quantile(Var1,.05, na.rm=TRUE),# lower quantile
q95 <- quantile(Var1,.95, na.rm=TRUE), # upper quantile
medx <- median(Var1, na.rm=TRUE), # median
x.dens <- density(df1$Var1, na.rm=TRUE)) # density
```

indeed, it is repeatedly the same operation, with the same settings, but different function.

Do you know how to overcome the elaborate use of code

Comment: Use within instead of with

Comment: It is better to check the `str` of each output before trying to create that as a column.  For example you can check `density` output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same results as your 'data.frame$' containing code by using `with`, you should explicitly assign the values to the global environment (Otherwise the values will be assigned in data environment and will not be returned):

```
with(df1,{ 
     q5 <<- quantile(Var1,.05, na.rm=TRUE) # lower quantile
     q95 <<- quantile(Var1,.95, na.rm=TRUE)  # upper quantile
     medx <<- median(Var1, na.rm=TRUE)  # median
     x.dens <<- density(df1$Var1, na.rm=TRUE)}) # density
```

The `<<-` function will do it.

Comment: That's great, I read about the <<- but did not found out how to use it in my case! Thank you very much

Comment: `assign` function will do this more safely. But in most cases, `<<-` is a shortcut.@Pharcyde

Comment: `<<-` is a non local operator and can cause side effects. This will not work, when you have the same variable in the environment other than the data frame. Try this and see what is the output of `df` and `a`.

Comment: using `<<-` inside `with`:  `a <- 1; df <- data.frame(d = 1:5); df <- with(df, a <<- 1:5); df`

Comment: using `<-` inside `within`:  `a <- 1; df <- data.frame(d = 1:5); df <- within(df, a <- 1:5); df`

Comment: @Pharcyde If you think `a` is very valuable and should not be mutated, then `<<-` will do otherwise, which will cause lot of troubles figuring out how `a` got mutated. It is not the recommended way, so I would discourage using it unless you have an application that requires it.

Comment: <<- is almost always bad practice. Outside of base R, dplyr::mutate or package:data.table will make for prettier repeated assignments.

Comment: I'm aware of the trouble that may be caused by `<<-`. I guess @Pharcyde just want to create those variables in workplace, not as colunms in data frame.  So I provided this solution.  But you are right, `<<-` is a dangerous operator and normally should be avoid. @Sathish

Comment: @Feng OP question says variable needs to be created in the data frame.

Comment: I remember @Gregor was downvoting my answer when I suggested `<<-` it to someone

Comment: In fact, I'm a little confused about whether OP wants the variables stored in workplace or as column. So I proposed my code which has the same results as OP's original code (as I said in my answer), not directly address this question. @Sathish

Answer (score 2):

use `within()` instead of `with` when you create a variable in the data frame environment.

```
res <- within(df1, 
              q5 <- quantile(Var1,.05, na.rm=TRUE),# lower quantile
              q95 <- quantile(Var1,.95, na.rm=TRUE), # upper quantile
              medx <- median(Var1, na.rm=TRUE), # median
              x.dens <- density(df1$Var1, na.rm=TRUE)) # density

head( res)
#      Var1     Var2       q5
# 1 4.943871 12.29145 3.678482
# 2 4.844204 11.55671 3.678482
# 3 3.529248 12.00111 3.678482
# 4 4.521850 12.07434 3.678482
# 5 5.417942 11.41048 3.678482
# 6 6.358680 11.43133 3.678482
```